# How to get Index of an enum value which has returned as Array?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two Problem with this code,

The first is that when I print it, Day 6 is not in order, it prints like this:

```
On Day1:Temperature was12
On Day2:Temperature was13
On Day3:Temperature was15
On Day4:Temperature was17
On Day5:Temperature was18
On Day7:Temperature was19
On Day8:Temperature was20
On Day9:Temperature was21
On Day6:Temperature was22
On Day10:Temperature was23
The Minimum Tempreature was 12,
The Maximum temperature was 23,
The average Temperature was 18,
```

The second problem is that when I print the days, I want to include also the days in which the Minimum and Maximum Temperatures toke place like this:

```
The Minimum Tempreature was 12, at Day 1
The Maximum temperature was 23,at Day 10
```

How Can I get the name of an enum based on its value?

this is the code for above prints,

This code takes enum (days, temperatures) as parameters and prints the days with their related temperatures and minimum, maximum and average....

```
// if user select February 


if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()== "February")
    {
        ShowsTempreatures(FebruaryMonth.Day2);

    }
 // The method which print and shows temperatures and minimum and maximum...

private void ShowsTempreatures(Enum February)
{
    int Minimumtemperture = 40;
    int Maximumtemperture = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int averageTemperatures = 0;

    // Return the values of Enum as an Array

    Array januaryData = Enum.GetValues(February.GetType());

    for (int i = 0; i < januaryData.Length; i++)
    {
        //printing the Days and Temperatures of enum February

        Label1.Text += string.Format("On {0}:Temperature was{0:D}<br/>", januaryData.GetValue(i));

        //finding out minimum and maximum and average temperatures

        int MonthTemp = (int)januaryData.GetValue(i);
        if (MonthTemp<Minimumtemperture)
        {
            Minimumtemperture = MonthTemp;

        }
        if (MonthTemp>Maximumtemperture)
        {
            Maximumtemperture = MonthTemp;
        }
        total = total + MonthTemp;
    }
    int totaltempretures = januaryData.Length;
    averageTemperatures = (total / totaltempretures);

    // printing the minimum,maximum and average temperature

    Label1.Text += string.Format("The Minimum Tempreature was {0},<br/> The Maximum temperature was {1},<br/> The average Temperature was {2},<br/> ",
            Minimumtemperture, Maximumtemperture, averageTemperatures);
}
private enum FebruaryMonth
{

    Day1 = 12,
    Day2 = 13,
    Day3 = 15,
    Day4 = 17,
    Day5 = 18,
    Day6 = 22,
    Day7 = 19,
    Day8 = 20,
    Day9 = 21,
    Day10 = 23
}
```

Comment: Could you post `enum February` ?

Comment: sorry I forgot to post it, I edited  the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this enum:

```
public enum DayOfMonth
{
    Day2 = 2,
    Day1 = 1
}
```

Here is how to get all the enums:

```
var days = Enum.GetValues(DayOfMonth.Day1.GetType()).Cast<DayOfMonth>().ToList(); 
Console.WriteLine(days[0]);
```

Here is how to get enum by its value. It is a simple cast:

```
DayOfMonth day2 = (DayOfMonth)2;
Console.WriteLine(day2);
```

Here is how to order them:

```
var ordered = days.OrderBy(x => x).ToList(); // or you can use OrderByDescending
Console.WriteLine(ordered[0]);
```

Comment: If I do the way you get all the enums, then I can't use Length Property and GetValue() method. I'm getting error: " cannot resolve Symbol" error

Comment: Use the `Count` property if it is a list, use `Count()` method if it is `IEnumerable`. Instead of `GetValue` use index `nameOfList[0]` and that will get you the value at index 0. If you still have difficulty, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, it worked,  is it the same approach for Dictionary<string,int> , should  I cast it or that is different?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but you can post a different question regarding that. A dictionary has a keyvalue pair so working with is different.

Comment: ok. I'll post it here. but before that can you explain a little about (x => x) parameters. what should go there?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Enum is **order by its Values** and not by the order of the name given to each value.

You can create a IComparer which will extract each value the name and compare it.

If we will compare the enum value names stricly by [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) we will intreduce a new bug. A bug which will tell us `Day10` is before `Day2`, because in lexicographical order 10 is small then 2. Thus, it leads us to try a  different way.

Another more accurate way, will be extracting the enum names and substring only the number portion, then we will parse them into integers and then apply the comparison.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Array januaryData = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FebruaryMonth));
        Array.Sort(januaryData, new FebruaryMonthSubstringComparer());
        for (int i = 0; i < januaryData.Length; i++)
        {
            string res = string.Format("On {0}:Temperature was{0:D}<br/>", januaryData.GetValue(i));
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }
}

public class FebruaryMonthSubstringComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        int monthX = int.Parse(Enum.GetName(typeof(FebruaryMonth), x).Substring(3)); // Naive parsing
        int monthY = int.Parse(Enum.GetName(typeof(FebruaryMonth), y).Substring(3));

        return monthX - monthY;
    }
}
```

Comment: in this line: Array.Sort(januaryData, new FebruaryMonthSubstringComparer()); i cant write FebruaryMonthSubstringComparer